# Java keystore failed PKCS12 integrity checking but keytool works

Tags: java, certificate

I have some PCKS12 certificate that is being served by two environments differently. When we upload it to a DEV environment, java can parse it. But it fails on a PRODuction. The server is Microsoft DotNet solution which is responsible for a certificate manipulation. The generated keystore has empty password. When I open the certificate in Windows I can successfully import it into the operating system - without a password.

I can list *DEV* certificate with keytool but the representation is strange:

```
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: {8c6xx9f-8041-49d2-95f7-3bcffxxxc8bcf}
Creation date: 15.5.2018
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry

*******************************************
*******************************************
```

But I can open it in java

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
keyStore.load(fis, "".toCharArray());
```

And browse it with Keystore Explorer:
[image]

I can list the *PROD* certificate correctly with keytool:

```
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: {9exx43e-83f8-405d-8f74-8b1xxxeaac37}
Creation date: 15.5.2018
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: OID.2.5.4.13=YCCere01, CN=CZ7, DC=CZ
Issuer: CN=EET CA 1, O=Česká Republika ? Generální finanční ředitelství, DC=CZ
Serial number: 84cxxxc6
Valid from: Wed May 09 16:11:43 CEST 2018 until: Sun May 09 16:11:43 CEST 2021
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  21:CB:24:AE:4D:F5:EE:4D:C9:6A:A0:DD:AA:2F:6F:A8
         SHA1: 02:0F:6B:C2:B8:E5:18:16:F9:49:28:4F:9E:F6:63:5C:D0:6E:6B:95
         SHA256: B8:37:57:66:1A:33:31:BD:DB:4E:AB:9C:E5:31:C3:18:2B:96:88:A9:1B:21:85:30:97:D9:BB:F7:84:7B:4A:52
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
         Version: 3
```

But both java and Keystore Explorer fails to open it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Integrity check failed: 
java.lang.SecurityException: Failed PKCS12 integrity checking
at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2058)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
at Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Failed PKCS12 integrity checking
at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2054)
```

Any idea where is the problem? The password is really empty because I was able to import the key into Windows without it. Keytool can list its content - so why does java API fail to open it with PKCS12 integrity checking error?

Comment: Surely the password is null rather than empty?

Comment: Wow, that works!

Comment: if you add an answer I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The password is incorrect or null. Also the password accepted can be base64