# Grepping stdout to attain specific strings, while avoiding repeats

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I was attempting to grep a command's stdout to only show the results between two strings. I wanted to print from the first case of 'Alias', to the first case of 'Valid' and then have that repeat again.

stdout: ("<---" are used to just show which lines I'm trying to print)

```
foo
bar
Alias: Name                        <---
fo bar
foo bar
Valid from: Monday Until: Thu May 26 12:44:38         <---
Valid from: Tuesday Until: Fri Nov 27 22:41:01 
Alias: Another_Name                                   <---
Valid from: Wednesday Until: Fri Nov 27 22:41:01         <---
Valid from: Friday Until: Thu Dec 04 23:31:58
Foo bar 
bar foo
```

piped expected output:

```
Alias: Name 
Valid from: Monday Until: Thu May 26 12:44:38
Alias: Another_Name 
Valid from: Wednesday Until: Fri Nov 27 22:41:01
```

Things I've Tried:

command | egrep "Alias:*|Valid*" #This also captures the second 'valid'
command | grep -P "Alias*|Valid*" #This again also captures the second 'valid..'

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** After discussion with OP, following code worked for OP well. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v IGNORECASE="1" '
/alias/{
  count=0
  aliasVal=$0
  next
}
aliasVal && /valid/ && ++count==1{
  print aliasVal ORS $0
}
' Input_file
```

---

This could be done in `awk` program, please try following once. Written and tested with your shown samples only.

```
awk '
/Alias:/{
  count=0
  aliasVal=$0
  next
}
aliasVal && /Valid from:/ && ++count==1{
  print aliasVal ORS $0
}
'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                      ##Starting awk program from here.
/Alias:/{                  ##Checking if line contains Alias: then do following.
  count=0                  ##Setting count to 0 here.
  aliasVal=$0              ##Setting aliasVal variable to current line value here.
  next                     ##Skipping all further statements from here.
}
aliasVal && /Valid from:/ && ++count==1{  ##Checking if aliasVal is set AND line contains Valid from: AND count is 1 then do following.
  print aliasVal ORS $0    ##Printing aliasVal ORS and current line here.
}
' Input_file               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

To run this in a bash script try something like:

```
cat script.bash
#!/bin/bash
awk '
/Alias:/{
  count=0
  aliasVal=$0
  next
}
aliasVal && /Valid from:/ && ++count==1{
  print aliasVal ORS $0
}
'   Input_file
```

Then give proper permissions to script and run it.

To run it from command line you can either run above non-one liner code OR following one liner code directly on terminal itself.

`awk '/Alias:/{count=0;aliasVal=$0;next} aliasVal && /Valid from:/ && ++count==1{print aliasVal ORS $0}' Input_file`

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13 , thanks for the response! A little new to bash so was wondering do  I just paste the above in a script? Is there a way to make it executable from the command line?

Comment: @Shak, yes, you could run this one liner on your terminal like: `awk '/Alias:/{count=0;aliasVal=$0;next} aliasVal && /Valid from:/ && ++count==1{print aliasVal ORS $0}'  Input_file` where Input_file is your file. Try it out and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13 I can't thank  you enough for the detailed explanation, however I'm using a commands output and piping it. "command | " is it possible to do it that way? Or is it necessary to produce a file?

Comment: @Shak, you could try like: `your_command | awk '/Alias:/{count=0;aliasVal=$0;next} aliasVal && /Valid from:/ && ++count==1{print aliasVal ORS $0}'` once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: it still isn't showing any output. Even though when I do something like command | grep -P "Alias.*|Valid.*" it produces results.

Comment: @Shak, with your shown samples this code works fine for me. What command are you using?

Comment: @Shak, I am not sure on keytool command. how about taking that command's output into a file and then run my `awk` command on that file? That should be fine, let me know.

Comment: yep tried. Its not printing anything out on console

Comment: It's odd because when I use the grep command I get an output, however with the awk and sed variants I haven't been able to get an output

Comment: @Shak, ok check your keytool command's output file once if it has control M characters? Run a command like `cat -v your_keytool_output_file` and let me know if you see control M characters?

Comment: can't find any control M characters

Comment: @Shak, check if your output file is same as shown samples?

Comment: yeah visually seems majority the same. The alias and Valid... parts are exactly the same

Comment: @Shak, try `awk '/[aA][Ll][Ii][Aa][Ss]:/{count=0;aliasVal=$0;next} aliasVal && /[vV][Aa][Ll][Ii][Dd] from:/ && ++count==1{print aliasVal ORS $0}' Input_file` once?

Comment: @Shak, or try `awk '/[aA][Ll][Ii][Aa][Ss]/{count=0;aliasVal=$0;next} aliasVal && /[vV][Aa][Ll][Ii][Dd]/ && ++count==1{print aliasVal ORS $0}' Input_file` once?

Comment: SUCCESS THAT WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Could I get an explanation of how it works and what ended up being the problem?

Comment: @Shak, there was a typo in that command please try `awk -v IGNORECASE="1" '/alias/{count=0;aliasVal=$0;next} aliasVal && /valid/ && ++count==1{print aliasVal ORS $0}' Input_file` once?

Comment: @Shak, Updated my answer with worked command now, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
awk -F: '$1==(f ? "Valid from" : "Alias name") {print; f=!f}'
```

Split on `:`, print when $1 is the expected value (which is alternated by flipping a variable around).

Or sed can use its range operator, followed by its special empty regex address (which uses the most recently used regex)

```
sed '/^Alias name:/,/^Valid from:/!d;//!d'
```

Comment: Hi @rowboat thanks for the answer but this doesn't seem to work with pipe. What I'm doing is "command |" and not storing it in a file.

Comment: According to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50363930/14473238), the output of `keytool` actually has `Alias name: ...` not `Alias: name` like you wrote in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a simple `sed`:

```sh
sed -n '/^Alias:/,/^Valid from:/ {//p;}' file

Alias: Name
Valid from: Monday Until: Thu May 26 12:44:38
Alias: Another_Name
Valid from: Wednesday Until: Fri Nov 27 22:41:01
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava thanks for the answer but this doesn't seem to work with pipe. What I'm doing is "command |" and not storing it in a file.

Comment: You can [see here in the demo that it works with pipeline](https://ideone.com/yxJ7Ni) also

Comment: Just use `your_command | sed -n '/^Alias:/,/^Valid from:/ {//p;}'`

Comment: @Shak there's nothing magic about input from a pipe vs from a file, it's all just input whether it's coming from `command | sed 'script'` or `sed 'script' file` and the same for awk.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/^Alias/{print; f=0} /^Valid/ && !f++' file
Alias: Name                        <---
Valid from: Monday Until: Thu May 26 12:44:38         <---
Alias: Another_Name                                   <---
Valid from: Wednesday Until: Fri Nov 27 22:41:01         <---
```